# Assigning fails with the second token lifetime policy with Graph-API endpoint POST /applications/{id}/tokenLifetimePolicies/$ref

Tags: rest, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, authorization

Assigning the first policy ID fails with the below Graph-API endpoint,
 `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{myAPPiD}/tokenLifetimePolicies/$ref Content-Type: application/json { "@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies/{2ndPolicyiD}" }`

## Repro Steps:

- Create tokenLifetimePolicies , POST policies/tokenLifetimePolicies
  Doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tokenlifetimepolicy-post-tokenlifetimepolicies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request
- Assign a tokenLifetimePolicy to an application with , /applications/{id}/tokenLifetimePolicies/$ref
  Doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-tokenlifetimepolicies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request
- Try assigning again with the above endpoint for a diffrent policy ID, and here comes the error
  HTTP Status Error code 409
  "code": "Request_MultipleObjectsWithSameKeyValue",

Is it that we cannot assign multiple policies to one target App ?

Comment: Similar question: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/21746 but still without the answer from MSFT. I guess that only one lifetime policy can be assigned.

Comment: exactly @user2250152 , this Graph-API endpoint is useful while we work on auth based scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> I agree with @user2250152, only one lifetime policy can be assigned to
> specific Azure AD application.

I created 2 token lifetime policies by running below query via Graph Explorer like this:

Policy 1:

**POST**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies
Content-type: application/json

{
    "definition": [
        "{\"TokenLifetimePolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"AccessTokenLifetime\":\"8:00:00\"}}"
    ],
    "displayName": "Kavya token lifetime policy 1",
    "isOrganizationDefault": false
}
```

[image]

Policy 2:

**POST** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies`

```
Content-type: application/json

{
    "definition": [
        "{\"TokenLifetimePolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"AccessTokenLifetime\":\"2:00:00\"}}"
    ],
    "displayName": "Kavya token lifetime policy 2",
    "isOrganizationDefault": false
}
```

Response:

[image]

Now, I assigned 1st token lifetime policy successfully to an application by running below query like this:

**POST** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/appObjectID/tokenLifetimePolicies/$ref`

```
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies/policy1_ID"
}
```

Response:

[image]

When I tried to assign second token lifetime policy to same application, I got same error as you like below:

POST `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/appObjectID/tokenLifetimePolicies/$ref`

```
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies/policy2_ID"
}
```

[image]

As only one token lifetime policy is allowed for one application, you need to delete token lifetime policy1 assignment in order to assign the other policy by running below query:

**DELETE** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/appObjectID/tokenLifetimePolicies/policy1_ID/$ref/`

RESPONSE:

[image]

When I ran the query again after deleting policy1 assignment, it assigned successfully like below:

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/appObjectID/tokenLifetimePolicies/$ref
Content-Type: application/json

{
"@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies/policy2_ID"
}

Response:

[image]

Note that, you can have multiple token lifetime policies in your tenant but can assign only one policy to specific application.

Comment: Yes, I was also able repro the same, thank you very much for trying out this at your end. However, the document does not exactly clarify while consuming the rest-API.

Comment: I have raised a PR with Microsoft to document this limitation and clear the confusion for the developer.